# MagickImage create same color irrespective of colorspace

Tags: .net, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to set the border color for any image from any colorspace to white. Right now I am doing something like,

```
if (image.ColorSpace == ColorSpace.CMYK)
  image.BorderColor = new MagickColor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Set border color as white (CMYK)
else
  image.BorderColor = new MagickColor("#FFFFFF"); // Set border color as white (RGB)
```

but this doesn't seem to be comprehensive, because in this case we need to look at other color spaces and see that they also fit into this.

I faced a problem where one image had colorspace as Lab, there the above code produces red borders. So I am looking for a simple way of doing this.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why bother? Just use the X11 color name, and let IM solve this problem. `new MagickColor("WHITE")`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a million.

Comment: Happy to help. Please post your solution as an answer & accept it. It'll help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @emcconville, I was able to get a simpler solution for this.

The MagickColor class accepts X11 color names as parameters, so we can achieve the same using

```
image.BorderColor = new MagickColor("WHITE");
```

This sets the border color as white irrespective of the ColorSpace.

For those of you wondering what X11 color names are, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names.